# Visual Studio 2013 Build Post-Build Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am using the default build template for Visual Studio 2013.  I have been using the pre-build script/post-build script options to run Powershell scripts for some time.  I have been able to access environment variables in these scripts, but now I need to access **properties** defined in the Visual Studio project.  The specific property I want to access in a post-build Powershell script is $Configuration.

I open the diagnostics of the builds I am executing.  I can confirm that the property is passed into the msbuild execution to build the project like this

```
/p:Configuration="Release"
```

I add to the post-build script arguments like this (I have also tried this with single quotes/double quotes/all caps)

```
-Configuration $Configuration
```

In the Powershell script itself I access the property value through the param like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
[string]$Configuration
)
```

I then try to write out the value of this parameter in the Powershell script like this

```
Write-Host "Checking Configuration: " + $Configuration
```

I can see this line when I look at the diagnostics from the build, but the problem is that the value of the parameter is always the string literal I pass into the post-build script arguments, but never the replacement parameter value of Debug or Release.  Here are some examples of what gets printed

> Checking Configuration: $Configuration
>
> Checking Configuration: "$Configuration"
>
> Checking Configuration: '$Configuration'
>
> Checking Configuration: $CONFIGURATION

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do - are project properties available to the post-build scripts?  It seems like this should be possible from reading other questions on this site as well as posts on other sites.  Is there something simple of complex I am missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `-Configuration $(Configuration)` for passing the argument? That's how it's normally done within the VS settings, since it goes like that into the project files which are interpreted by msbuild and $(property) is the syntax used by msbuild

Comment: Yes - I have tried combinations with the parenthesis like $(CONFIGURATION) OR $(Configuration) OR '$(Configuration)' but the end result in the build diagnostics is the same, I get outputs like "Checking Configuration: + $(CONFIGURATION)" OR
"Checking Configuration: + $(Configuration)" OR
"Checking Configuration: + '$(Configuration)'".  I tried each of these combinations again just to be certain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved by adding the variable into **Environment variables** to the **Run Script** task in XAML Build.

[image]